# GraphQL Mesh sharing types across handler or different sources

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi, graphql-mesh

I am working on a project with `GraphQL Mesh`.

With one of the use cases I have one `openapi` endpoint. In there, I need to handcraft a resolver that is using types from that openapi schema definations. I tried using different `handlers`, but types are not sharing across. I also tried to add multiple sources inside one handler, but the customised one (in 2nd place) is not showing in the schema.

If anyone know how to deal with this case, lease help me out. Thank you.

I am expecting to use types from the `openapi` spec in the custome handler.